# android and server

Tags: android

im really new to this so dont spare any answer even if its really basic..

i want to make an android app that sends a number to a server, and i want the server to check its data base if any other users entered the same number. I want the server to reply which number has the same number.

i also want the server to send the other users that holds this number a messege about a new user that hold this number.

i hoped i made myself clear.

i have no idea where to start... how to write the server side (language/where do i get a free server)?

thanks

Comment: If this is something your app will rely on I would recommend paying for a server and based on your experience use either a windows or linux server. Linux will save you the licence fee using Apache or you could use IIS on windows if you like. Language depends entirely on what you want to write it in, your question is too vague for me to make a recommendation as I don't know your experience. Writing an API is a good route to take though, that way you can change the server later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should (must) learn Java to write the client side application (the Android application)

Second, you have a lot of free servers. [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a good solution as it's based on Java too. It's up to you to write your own servlet that makes what you want.

Also an important thing to keep in mind is how are you going to send the other users a message. Since it's only the server who knows when that happens, you'll have to either wait until they connect to the server, or actively open a connection from server to client -that if you know the client IP address, which can be (and most likely is) dynamic-.

(I'm assuming you want to acheive this through TCP/IP)

Comment: the client side is less of an issue right now,
im focusing the server side.
is using apache tomcat allow me to make the server initiate msgs? (suppose i know the ip dest)

Answer (score 0):

You have many questions, and very general. You can send data to a webserver with an [aSyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and an [HTTPClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html). Doesn't matter what language you have on your server side, PHP is the most common and you can find many [free hosts](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=free%20php%20hosting).

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple..... You have to use JSON to do mobile and server communication.... You have to write webservice,php script on server side and Http connection in client side.  Please gothrough the following link I have used same link for mobile and server communication....
http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/